How to bring a question from Biblical Hermeneutics for answer here?
I have seen a question on Biblical Hermeneutics to which a Jewish answer would be interesting to me. How do I introduce it here? It is https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/95610/how-are-leviticus-1524-and-leviticus-2018-meant-to-be-understood-together

I'd suggest simply posting a similar question here and giving credit to there for the inspiration.
See also this old Meta question: What is Mi Yodeya's position on cross-posting? In this case, you'd only be posting here, so I'd recommend linking your question here to there and then commenting there with a link to here, rather than trying to coerce the cross-linking on that side by editing.

Note also if the question was off topic on BH but on topic here we could ask the mods to migrate it over.

Fair warning about BH: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1807/31534

I would also advise against contributing on philosophy SA for similar reasons. I gave a theological answer to a theological question, about ex nihilo (so not even davka Jewish), and it was immediately criticised, in a way that did not reflect good faith and honest desire to learn. Instead, it was a very touchy, reactionary set of comments that all basically said "this is an atheist space, [insert 12 year old level jokes about God and religion], go away"
